# enable/disable form control fires valueChanges Angular 2 Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Any ideas why when running the following code I get the `valueChanges` event  of `'firstName'` control fired?

```js
let form: FormGroup = this.createForm();
form.controls['firstName'].enable();

form.controls['firstName'].valueChanges(value=>{
      //some code
});
```

As no value has changed (just the status), I wouldn't expect `valueChanges` to be triggered here, only the `statusChanged`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: statusChanged is for validations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Basically complete form is mapped on a model, so whenever you enable/disable any control, the form model's property changes. And because the model is changing so `valueChanges` event will be triggered. I think its normal.

Comment: Some suggestions on how to avoid it besides using `this.form.controls[controlKey].enable({emitEvent:false});` ?

Comment: They say there is a bug with this feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12366

Comment: You are a lifesaver

Comment: god damn great comment @Ben

Comment: @Ben Great JERB!

Answer (score 44):

No idea why it behaves as it does, but you can send `emitEvent: false` to enable/disable without firing `valueChanges`.

```
form.controls['firstName'].enable({ emitEvent: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, googling wasn't leading us anywhere!

Comment: Thank you. Note that it also work when you try to enable or disable the whole form: `form.enable({ emitEvent: false });`

Comment: Sigh, this should work the other way round... It should be false by default and developer should change it to true if needed... Who thought it's a good idea lol

Answer (score 15):

I have angular version 6.0.3

```
this.form.get('inputName').setValue(newValue, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
```

This works for me.

Comment: OP is asking in `Angular 2` not in 6

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me. Thanks for posting the answer!

Comment: @Narendra Jadhav: AngularJS was the original framework. That should always be written as AngularJS. With "Angular" or "Angular 2" you mean the new version of Angular. This has a version number, like 6.0.3. So Angular2 6.0.3 is okay for me.

Comment: This seems to be blocking the setValue but question is about blocking the enabled/disabled state, how to adapt your solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

`ValueChange` getting triggered on enabling or disabling a form in angular is a bug in their code.

If you dont want the `ValueChange` to be triggered on enabling or disabling the form,
I found a workaround which may help.

```
Object.keys(this.toolForm.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.form.controls[key].enable({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
});
```

The above code fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Is this behaviour mentioned somewhere in the angular reactive forms documentation? Otherwise it's hard to say it's a bug, perhaps it's by design.

Comment: In https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12366 there are a lot of discussion on the same issue.